# How to update first name and last name text fields into name field and picklist values into another field

Tags: workflow, formula, process-builder

[image]

Hi All,

I have a requirement where I want to update values from
1. B_Caller First Name and B_Caller Last name(both text datatype) into Name field (Name datatype)
2.Best Call Back Time-Caller (picklist value) into Best callback Time-Patient(picklist value)
3.Caller street,Caller state,Caller city,Caller zip(all text data types into Address field (address datatype)

When Copy Caller to patient checkbox is checked.

Please help me !!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy picklist values from one into another](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/102856/how-to-copy-picklist-values-from-one-into-another)

Comment: Note, the other question has already been closed as the duplicate of this one.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can create a process in lightning builder to complete where you will define Copy Caller to patient checkbox as entry criteria. this is very simple and easy method where you don't need to write any code

   Go to **Setup-> Create-> Workflow & Approval -> Process builder.**

[image]

if you are unfamiliar with process builder you can learn this from trailhead

https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/business_process_automation/process_builder

2. You can write a trigger on your object (before insert, before update) which can perform the same operation.

Comment: Hi Himanshu,I am new to workflows and validation rules,I don't have knowledge about triggers,is it possible through workfows and validation rules

Comment: yes that is possible using workflow and process builder is advance version of workflow which gives you power to define workflow by point and click in interactive UI.

Comment: Can you please help me in this

Comment: yes sure. follow the steps as shown in screenshot.

Comment: check the process builder from trailhead https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/business_process_automation/process_builder